# Need the state of a Firebase thread

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-authentication

I´m using Firebase and in the login screen I have a method that it´s called when the user put the correct login credentials(that method start a Firebase thread in order to get all the info I need for the main screen), and when the main screen opened I need to wait until that method finish, I need some kind of flag or something, let me paste you my code:

Login.java:

```
mProgress.setMessage("Verificando Datos Usuario...");
                    mProgress.show();
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(usuario, pass)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Los Datos administrados no son correctos",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        mProgress.dismiss();
                                    } else{
                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Bienvenido... ",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       AdminFirebase.loadAdmin(task.getResult().getUser());

                                        mProgress.dismiss();
                                        Intent intento=new Intent(Login.this, Principal.class);
                                        startActivity(intento);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

AdminFirebase.java:

```
public static void loadAdmin(FirebaseUser user){

        DatabaseReference userRef=adminRef.child(user.getUid());
        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Administrador administrador=dataSnapshot.getValue(Administrador.class);
                Sesion.admin=administrador;
                Sesion.admin.loadTaxis();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

    });
```

the method I need to wait to finish to run it´s on the class Taxifirebase.java:

```
    public static void loadTaxis(List<String> chapas){

             for (String chapa :chapas) {
                 DatabaseReference taxiref=childRef.child(chapa);
                 taxiref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        Taxi taxi=dataSnapshot.getValue(Taxi.class);
                        Sesion.taxis.add(taxi);

                     }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the flag is for you can use [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class.

If you need for the logic of program use a boolean and change to `true` when you need. Later you can check the value.

Comment: I need it for the logic, I need the thread to finish in order to have the data in the main class, and if I use a simple boolean it can´t be accedes outside of the thread.

Comment: Then is a boolean, you dont need a boolean inside the thread, you must read about java access modifiers + knowledge about class and POO, you can create a flags available in your program or app